# react js как из дочернего передать в родительский

Tags: reactjs, react-hook

Я вроде правильно написал но всё равно не работает, вот код:

APP:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Increment from "./Increment&Decrement"

function App() {

    const [name, satename]=useState("gg");

     const placehh = (name)=>{
         satename(name)
     }

     return (
      <div className="App">
          <h1>{name}</h1>
          <Increment onChanger={placehh}/>
      </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: похоже, вы забыли указать код дочернего компонента

Answer (score 0):

В дочернем компоненте вызовите коллбэк `onChanger`, который вы передаете в `props`:

```js
function Increment = ({ onChanger }) => {

    return <div onClick={() => onChanger('John')}>Set name</div>

}

export default Increment
```